# How to prevent characters being submitted with form input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I'm in the process of creating a gambling website, but currently with the betting form input you can type a negative number etc (-100) and you will have 100 coins put into your balance.

I need to restrict the use of anything but number digits being used within the input. Currently my work around is blocking the user from typing in anything other than numbers but you are able to hop into the developer tools and insert the value manually.

I believe i need to have an onSubmit validation for the input which says if anything but numbers are inserted do not allow the submit.

I'm not sure how i will do this, thanks for the help!

Comment: even if you validate it client side, always validate it server side as well

Comment: apply number validation both at client side (through jquery) and server side (through php)

Answer (score 0):

```
put onkeypress="return onKeyValidate(event,alpha);" on your input box,and         
call the function

function onKeyValidate(e,charVal){
var keynum;
var keyChars = /[\x00\x08]/;
var validChars = new RegExp(charVal);
if(window.event)
{
    keynum = e.keyCode;
}
else if(e.which)
{
    keynum = e.which;
}
var keychar = String.fromCharCode(keynum);
if (!validChars.test(keychar) && !keyChars.test(keychar))  
{
    return false
} else{
    return keychar;
}

}
```

Comment: The OP already has this part covered: *"Currently my work around is blocking the user from typing in anything other than numbers"* - though in any case a key handler isn't enough because the user may edit the field without using the keyboard. The question is explicitly asking about validation **on submit**.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ctype_digit()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php)

```
//returns true
<?php
if (ctype_digit('123')) {
    echo 'true';
} else {
    echo 'false' ;
}
?>


//returns false
<?php
if (ctype_digit('-123')) {
    echo 'true';
} else {
    echo 'false' ;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this reguler expression to validate for numbers

samp html `<button type="submit" onclick="myfunc()">Click Me!</button>`

```
function myfunc(){
var a = /^\d*$/;
{
if(!a.test(value of input))
{
    alert('Please provide a Number');
    return false;
}
} 
}
```

here

- / at both ends mark the start and end of the regex
- ^ and $ at the ends is to check the full string than for partial  matches
- d* looks for multiple occurrences of number charcters

if you want only positive numbers use this`/^[+]?([0-9]+(?:[\.][0-9]*)?|\.[0-9]+)$/`

Comment: The question says that the OP doesn't know how to do validation **on submit.** Presumably some sort of submit handler is going to be necessary...

Answer (score -1):

this jquery code can solve your problem

```
$(function(){
        $("#submit").click(function(evnt){
            var inptTxt = $("#myField").val();

            if(check(inptTxt)){
                //your test true then submits
                $('#form').submit;
            }else{  //test failed
                evnt.preventDefault();
            }
        })
    })
```

here the `#submit` is the id of submit button and `#form` is the id of the form to be submitted